# Unity3D with WPF application

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine

Currently, I am working on WPF project where I have various types data of a machine. I want to draw my machine according to my data in unity3d view. And this unity3d view will be in included in my wpf application window.For this, how can I connect the unity3d engine with my corresponding wpf application?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate because it is on Unity's Q&A site, but here is pretty much the exact same question from over there http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/245242/is-it-possible-to-use-unity-inside-wpf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to Windows Communication Foundation [WCF]

Mono does support this:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/

I haven't tried it however try these links:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4cXuiZyJQ8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vROXfatVTJQ

Fallback would be NamedPipeServer/Client using my previous post that should hopefully work now [untested on Unity 5]

[named pipe client won't work in unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582846/named-pipe-client-wont-work-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a window store project then build it. Unity will generate a sln which does contains the framework for window store.  Looking at that project you can see where it puts the unity container window in the xaml. This is the high level starting point that you'll need to do it correctly.  A lot of how it works changed frequently between the unity versions so not much point in me pasting links here.  At a high level there is a xaml frameworkElement that hosts Direct3d content which unity hooks into.